# updating value of a specific key in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an array in redux state/store like this `[{"answer": "yes", "questionId": 2},{"answer": "yes", "questionId": 3}]`

I want to only update answer of an object based on id. like this if this is state and user send `{"answer": "no", "questionId": 2}`. how to update this state in redux? or just remove this object with questionId of 2 and add the one user sent?

```
return {
       ...state,
       answers: [...state.answers[0].answer, payload.answer],
          };
```

this does not works

```
return {
        ...state,
        answers[0].answer: [...state.answers, payload.answer],
          };
```

and this is not permissible.. keeping in mind this array can only store 2 objects. Task is user sends 2 answers and i have to store them in store or array of answers if that answers is not already in array and if it is in array then only update that specific answer.

i tried this also but it does not works as expected.

```
for (i = 0; i <= state.answers.length; i++) {
        if (state.answers[i]?.questionId === payload.questionId) {
            state.answers.splice(
             state.answers.indexOf(payload),
             1,
           );
         
          return {
            ...state,
            answers: [...state.answers, payload.answer],
          };
        } else {
          return {
            ...state,
            answers: [...state.answers, payload],
          };
        }
```

Comment: So are you asking how to change an object in an array? If you think of it this way, the question has nothing to do with redux. The answer is to find the object then change it. Which leads us to think...should answers be an array to begin with? Maybe it makes more sense for answers to be an object with the `questionId` as a key. This would make it much faster to find an answer when we need to update part of it.

Comment: no it does bcuz in simple js `return { ...state,
        answers[0].answer: [...state.answers, payload.answer],
          };` this would have worked

Comment: Right. The modification you need to make is more complex than just adding a new answer to the array. So you need to find a different solution. Again, this is about creating a new array with the data you want which is independent of redux. The only thing related to redux is that you then return the array from your reducer after you build it. The actual building of the new array is plain ol' JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.findIndex to find the index of the target object that needs to be updated then replace the object at this index with the new one.

```
//Make deep copy of state
let tempAnswers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.answers));

let targetAnswerIndex = tempAnswers.findIndex(answer => {
    return answer.questionId === payload.answer.questionId
});

tempAnswers[targetAnswerIndex] = payload.answer;
state.answers = tempAnswers;
```

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.